# How to inherit Express router and also call super inside method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

**Express Router** the function I want to "inherit"/extend

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  router.__proto__ = proto;

  router.params = {};
  router._params = [];
  router.caseSensitive = opts.caseSensitive;
  router.mergeParams = opts.mergeParams;
  router.strict = opts.strict;
  router.stack = [];

  return router;
};
```

So the purpose would be to create my own function/class to extend this express router and override the `route` method to accept an extra parameter but also being able to call `super.route` of Express router

I've tried several ways, including `util.inherits` but nothing worked.

If possible please provide some explanations also

End goal is something like this:

```
var testRouter = express.Router();

testRouter.route('/test-route', 'aaa' /* my extra param here */)
    .get(controller.testWhatever)
```

Being able to override the route method to add a new parameter but preserve the old functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Think this example explains what you are looking for

```
// Create a class
function Vehicle(color){
  this.color = color;
}

// Add an instance method
Vehicle.prototype.go = function(){
  return "Underway in " + this.color;
}

// Add a second class
function Car(color){
  this.color = color;
}

// And declare it is a subclass of the first
Car.prototype = new Vehicle();

// Override the instance method
Car.prototype.go = function(){
  return Vehicle.prototype.go.call(this) + " car"
}

// Create some instances and see the overridden behavior.
var v = new Vehicle("blue");
v.go() // "Underway in blue"

var c = new Car("red");
c.go() // "Underway in red car"
```